# Metabase multi filter - "Incorrect syntax near '='" error

Tags: sql, metabase

I have a problem with metabase, I want to count total employee absence from multi table.

I want the result can count based on date I put in the filter.

When I run the query the result show "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Here is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Name_tbl p, period_tbl epr, Data_tbl e 
LEFT JOIN Name_tbl ps ON e.person_id = ps.person_id 
LEFT JOIN absence_tbl ec ON e.company_id = ec.company_id 
                         AND e.id = ec.id  
                         AND ec.absence_date = [[{{validdate}}]] 
LEFT JOIN absence_detail_tbl ect ON ec.company_id = ect.company_id 
                                 AND ec.id = ect.id  
                                 AND ect.absence_date = [[{{validdate}}]] 
WHERE e.person_id = p.person_id 
  AND e.company_id = epr.company_id 
  AND e.id = epr.id 
  AND epr.valid_to >= [[{{validdate}}]]
```

Can you guys help me to fix it??
thank you

Comment: sorry typo, there is a space betewwn FROM & Name_tbl.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And mixing old comma-separated style with proper ANSI JOIN's in the same query is **doubly bad**....

Comment: The problem when there are typos in the code you're showing us (I know you've since corrected it, but...) is that it means *you have not run the code you're showing us*. Can you confirm that you've copied and pasted the *actual code you've shown us in your question*, executed it, and confirmed that it's still giving the error the question is about please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry for the typo but I copy & paste the actual query code. I execute the code and the error still the same "Incorrect syntax near '='."